# Change Web-to-lead Activity mail

Tags: web2lead

An old employee set up our Web-to-lead through "WordPress-to-lead for Salesforce CRM." That works with our website. When we get a lead a form email gets sent out and an activity/task is logged. I would like to be able to change the subject of the activity/task, but have not been able to find where this is possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Setup > Customize > Leads > Assignment Rules / Settings, I'd guess, but I don't know enough about that WP module.

Comment: unfortunately it is not in either of those places

Comment: I'm guessing you either have a workflow rule or trigger that is creating the tasks, I do not believe the web2lead has an out of a box way of creating tasks. To see if there is a trigger go to Setup->Customize->Leads->Triggers, to see if there is a workflow rule go to Setup->Create->Workflow Rules(if you have a bunch - create a view with object=Lead).

Answer (score 1):

That's our plugin, we sponsor it.

If you're referring to tasks being created in Salesforce, and emails being sent to Salesforce users, then that's unrelated to the plugin. If you're referring to an email being sent to the form submitter, you may be getting that from Salesforce, or from the plugin if you've given the user the option to send a copy to themselves of the form.

As for the email you get internally, that's slightly hidden in Salesforce. The email template will be in 'Email Templates' but the choice of which template is under Lead > Assignment Rules > Rule Name, and then edit the respective rules to see which template is the active one for that rule.

As for the email sent to the customer, Leads > Auto-Response Rules. As I recall, auto-responses are logged as a task.